# Google Cloud Monitoring - Custom Dashboard - Changing chart background

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I have configured a custom dashboard in GCP Monitoring, where I have added different different charts.

Some of the charts form a logical group. I would like to make this visible by changing the background color of these charts of the dashboard and use the same background color for the charts that form a group.

Is this possible in a custom dashboard of the GCP Monitoring product?